# Python 3 , load key value from Yaml as varible

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I am looking to create a new folder for each item under the folders key as below.
Yaml file is as below

```
---
software:
  dir: C:/software
folders:
  - bob:
      ip:
        - "192.168.1.5"
        - "192.168.1.6"
      password:
        - kdhkfjhkjdkjfjsikd
  - alice:
      ip:
        - "192.168.1.3"
      password:
        - hfsdkljfdhkjsfkjfsd
```

Python Code

```
from sys import path
import requests
import os
import yaml

with open('config.yaml') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f, yaml.loader.FullLoader)+

for i in config["folders"]:
    for f in i.values():
        print(i)
```

I am just using print as its easier to understand the data.
This returns

```
{'bob': {'ip': ['192.168.103.5', '192.168.103.6'], 'password': ['kdhkfjhkjdkjfjsikd']}}
{'alice': {'ip': ['192.168.105.3'], 'password': ['hfsdkljfdhkjsfkjfsd']}}
```

now what I want to happen is just return the folder names, e.g. bob, alice.
I have tried the below with no luck, thank you.

```
for i in config["folders"]:
for f in i.values():
    print(i[0])
```

which returns

```
print(i[0])
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the folder names with:

```py
import yaml

with open('config.yaml') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f, yaml.loader.FullLoader)

folder_names = [list(folder)[0] for folder in config["folders"]]
```

Comment: Or just `list(config["folders"])` – iterating over a dict iterates over the keys.

Comment: I have edited my answer, does it work now?

Comment: @JMA thank you, it works perfect and I can now mark as answered finally :D

Answer (score 0):

You should always be aware of what type the variables are. You can check this using the `type()` function.

Some examples:

- `type(config)` should give you `<class 'dict'>`
- `type(config["folders"])` should give you `<class 'list'>`, as it is a list of dictionaries.

When you do

```
for i in config["folders"]:
    print(i[0])
```

every `i` in the loop corresponds to an item of list `config["folders"]`, which itself is a dictionary. Therefore, with `i[0]`, you try to access the dictionary item with key `0`, which does not exist.

Instead, you probably want to print the first key of the dictionary with:

```
for i in config["folders"]:
    print(list(i.keys())[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm the types are as you described. Trick added to my book now.
But the following error now occurs `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`
Thank you, I can now research this :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, you need to convert them to a list first. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import yaml

with open('yamer.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

data = data.get('folders')

for x in data:
    for i in x.keys():
        print(i)
```

It basically "gets" the dictionary with the key "folders" from data dict. Then we can iterate through it as shown above and print the folder names. You can create a list and start appending the names (strings) to it if needed.
Thank you!